# Shopify API - How can i update product order on Smart Collection with thousands of products?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shopify

I am using Shopify's Ruby Gem to organize Smart Collections in a product store. Essentially I am trying to do a nightly update to the product order on these collections (their sort order is set to manual). The goal is to sort products based on sales data, but also put out of stock items at the end of the list.

I managed to write a script that works well on most collections:

```
@scs = ShopifyAPI::SmartCollection.find(:all,params: {limit: 250})
@scs.each do |sc|
        sc.order(products: @products_in_order)
        sc.save
end
```

Unfortunately if the collection is larger than a couple hundred products, the URI becomes too long and I get this error:

> ActiveResource::ClientError: Failed.  Response code = 414.  Response
>   message = Request-URI Too Large.

Is there any way to update product order on large smart collections in an efficient way? Some of my collections have upwards of 1000 products, and I do not want to have to update each "collect" individually as I will be running this script on a daily basis.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your current technique is limited. The first thing you probably want to do is iterate all the collections by paging. Not paging means you'll never touch all the products in the collections with more than 250 products.

Second, as you page, per collection, build a hash with the details needed to sort them. Otherwise, you're storing a whole bunch of memory hungry hippos that will blow your memory footprint to hell. Use the hash to then order the products and save them.

And since this is scripting, and can run at night, suck it up and sort/store by product. Not like you're picking tomatoes or watermelons with your brute strength.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your response. I do pull all the products. The above limit is for the collections query ( i have fewer than 250 collections ). The variable @products_in_order includes all products in the collection. The problem is if there are hundreds of products, the URI of the API call becomes too long.. There is no problem assigning sort order product by product, except when you have thousands of products and hundreds of collections...This could easily turn into 30k API calls per day and does not seem like the wisest use of resources...

Comment: Why would you want to do this anyway? A collection with 1000s of products becomes pretty unwieldy anyway (customer is not going to page through them all). At any rate it sounds like the code is broken. The order by update should be a PUT so there shouldn't be any URI length consideration.  If that is actually and the error is mis-labelled by Shopify what happens when you do the update in batches? If you apply a group of 100 what happens when you apply a second group of 100 product ids?